# Xcode 9.4 : unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed

Tags: ios11, build-error, swift4.1, xcode-workspace, xcode9.4

I’m getting strange error while building project in Xcode 9.4

```
Build system information - unexpected service error: The Xcode build system has crashed. Please close and reopen your workspace.
```

[image: Screenshot attached]

I tried *Xcode quit and reopen but that didn’t worked.* Any solution?

Comment: I'm constantly getting this for a certain project with Xcode 10.0 beta. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: @Locksleyu : Didn't found anything.

Comment: I'm having this problem, did you fix it? @JayprakashDubey

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Please clear derived data folder (located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData) and restart the Xcode project.

Comment: This iOS eng equivalent of "did you try turning it off and turning it back on" for Xcode :-). Sad but true! This fixes a lot of weird issues with Xcode.

Answer (score 45):

This error usually happens between Xcode major versions. Apple usually claim their new build system is ** times faster than their previous version. If you see this error(I see this on changing Xcode9 to Xcode10 beta), you can always change it to the legacy build system. Here is how you can do this:

1. **Open 'workspace settings'( it is now changed to 'Project Settings' if you are using Xcode10 or later) in the File Menu**
   [image]
2. **Change build system to '*legacy*'**
   [image]

Comment: In XCode 10 Workspace Settings is now called Project Settings.

Comment: This resolves similar error issue that occurs when you downgrade from XCode 10.2 to XCode 10.1. Thanks.

Comment: Also solved the problem with XCode 11 Beta 4 for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Update for Xcode 13.4.1:

I had this infamous bug today as well. I tried a lot including clean project, delete derived, restart max etc.

What did the fix finally is similar to the answer of kakaiikaka: I set the workspace settings to "Legacy Build System (Deprecated)" for both, the shared and per user workspace. I tried to build with this, but got an error because I had packages wich are not supported.
Restarted Xcode, then changed back the build system. Restarted Xcode again.
Now the crash doesn't happen any more.

Looks like something internal was spoilt and cycling the build system fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I moved a lot of files all at once between folders, including nested folders.  This error started happening.  Nothing I did in regards to cleaning, purging derived data, or undoing the move operation would help.

What I did to help was:  restore the previous version of the project file from source control and then re-add all the applicable new files to it.  It was project file related.   Deleting user data inside the project container did not help in my case.  So as long as you use source control and can rollback the .xcodeproj, this may be an option.

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me when i changed build configuration names. After deleting Pods folder and Podfile.lock, and then runnnig "pod install" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 10.2 delete podfile, podfile.lock, xcworkspace, open terminal, cd directory of project, `pod init`, add pods you want to pod file, `pod install`, open xcworkspac. Everything will be indexing now and then you can build.